# Is it a convergent series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

If $f(x)$ is a continuous function, does
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n\times \left[f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) + f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)+\cdots+f\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)\right]$$

converge?

Comment: Can you explain with your transactions ?

Comment: Please, this is regular textbook stuff. This site never was meant to be a replacement for textbooks.

Comment: As written, this diverges.   Consider the function $f(x)=1$.   Presumably you meant to divide by $n$..  Assuming that is the case, then this is a standard part of the theory of the Riemann Integral.  You should be able to find plenty of references for that.

Comment: I wanted mathematical operation because my english is not enough, don't get me wrong

Comment: @lulu The original post had this factor before an edit removed it.

Comment: @PeterForeman  You are absolutely right.  I have restored that factor to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that if $ f$ is integrable at $[a,b]$, then 
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(a+k\frac{b-a}{n}\right)=\int_a^bf(x)dx$$

in your case, $f$ is continuous at $[0,1]$, then it is integrable and

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(\frac kn\right)=$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{1-0}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(0+k\frac{1-0}{n}\right)$$
$$=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

So, the sum is convergent.

Comment: so, is it convergence or divergence ?

Comment: @FurkanKaya It converges to the integral.

Comment: Your final sum needs a factor of $1/n$.

Comment: Note that the OP does not have that factor of $\frac 1n$ in the question.  Without that, then of course one expects the sum to diverge.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Yes, of course. thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks everyone.